# Why Mapsui.UI.Forms does not exist?

Tags: forms, user-interface, mapsui

I Install Mapsui (v1.4.8) in my project and I wan't be able to put pins on my map.

So I search on google and I found that's possible with a MapView in Mapsui.UI.Forms.

But when I go in Mapsui.UI, the .Form does not exist.

I try to install the Mapsui.Forms(v0.2) nugget but it still doesn't exist. 
I already tried to change my Xamarin.Forms version, I passed from 4.2.0 to 2.5.1, but that change nothing.

So, did I miss something else to install ?

Thank's for your help

Answer (score 0):

The Xamarin.Forms support is in a separate package. v0.2.1 is the one that works with Mapsui 1.4.8.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mapsui.Forms/0.2.1

The documentation in Mapsui on XF is written for v2 so will probably not apply to XF use in 1.4.8.